# Why doesn't my ToDoDate field accept the date in the format specified according to @JsonFormat?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to create a todo application in springboot for practice and am trying to add toDoDate using postman however I am getting the following error:

Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "09/07/2026": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '09/07/2026': Cannot parse date "09/07/2026": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

ToDoController.java

```
package com.lcwd.todo.controllers;

import com.lcwd.todo.models.ToDo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.lcwd.todo.services.ToDoService;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todos")
public class ToDoController {

    @Autowired
    private ToDoService toDoService;
    Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToDoController.class);

    Random random=new Random();
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ToDo> createToDoHandler(@RequestBody ToDo todo){
        logger.info("created todo");
        Date date=new Date();
        todo.setAddedDate(date);
        int id= random.nextInt(9999);
        todo.setId(id);
        ToDo todo1=toDoService.createToDo(todo);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todo1,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ToDo>> getAllToDo(){
        logger.info("Received all todos");
        List<ToDo> todos=toDoService.getAllToDo();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todos,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{toDoId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ToDo> getSingleToDo(@PathVariable("toDoId") int id){
        ToDo todo=toDoService.getSingleToDo(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todo,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{todoId}")
    public String updateSingleToDo(@PathVariable("todoId") int id,@RequestBody ToDo todo){
       String answer=toDoService.updateToDo(id,todo);
       return answer;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{toDoId}")
    public String getDeleteToDo(@PathVariable("toDoId") int id){
        toDoService.deleteToDo(id);
        return "Deleted Successfully";
    }
}
```

ToDo.java

```
package com.lcwd.todo.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class ToDo {
    private String content;
    private String title;
    private String status;
    private int id;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date toDoDate;
    private Date addedDate;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getToDoDate() {
        return toDoDate;
    }

    public void setToDoDate(Date toDoDate) {
        this.toDoDate = toDoDate;
    }

    public Date getAddedDate() {
        return addedDate;
    }

    public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }

    public ToDo(String content, String title, String status, int id, Date toDoDate, Date addedDate) {
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
        this.id = id;
        this.toDoDate = toDoDate;
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ToDo{" +
                "content='" + content + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", toDoDate=" + toDoDate +
                ", addedDate=" + addedDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

ToDoService.java

```
package com.lcwd.todo.services;

import com.lcwd.todo.models.ToDo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Component
public class ToDoService {

    ArrayList<ToDo> todos=new ArrayList<>();

    Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToDoService.class);

    public ToDo createToDo(ToDo todo) {
        logger.info("Todos {}",this.todos);
        todos.add(todo);
        return todo;
    }

    public List<ToDo> getAllToDo() {
        return todos;
    }

    public ToDo getSingleToDo(int id){
        ToDo toDo;
        for(ToDo todo1:todos){
            if(todo1.getId()==id){
                return todo1;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String updateToDo(int id,ToDo todo) {
        for(ToDo todo1:todos){
            if(todo1.getId()==id){
                todo1.setContent(todo.getContent());
                todo1.setTitle(todo.getTitle());
                todo1.setStatus(todo.getStatus());
            }
        }
        return "updated successfully";
    }

    public void deleteToDo(int id) {
        int index=0;
        for(ToDo todo:todos){
            if(todo.getId()==id){
                index=todos.indexOf(todo);
                todos.remove(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Json object passed is:

```
    {
    "content":"Hello",
    "status":"DONE",
    "title":"Rppo",
    "toDoDate":"09/07/2026"
    }
```

@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date toDoDate;

Comment: As an aside, consider using the `java.time` API instead of `Date`.

Comment: Why isn't Date working @JsonFormat

Comment: Not sure. Nor was my comment attempting to answer your question (hence the "as an aside" bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that - in absence of a no-argument constructor - Jackson uses the provided constructor to create an instance of the *ToDo* class.
Since parameter names for constructors are removed during compilation, Jackson can not know which field corresponds to which constructor argument and can't use the `@JsonFormat` annotation present on the *toDoDate* field.

Adding a no-arg constructor will fix the issue.
You can also annotate the constructor arguments with `@JsonProperty` annotation to prevent the error (see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects).

Comment: Yes you are right why did this happen?

Comment: You can also adjust Jackson deserialization, e.g. with '@JsonCreator' and '@JsonProperty' annotations. Then no default constructor is needed. See e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects

Comment: @ssc1234 Most likely, without a no-argument constructor, Jackson _has_ to use the constructor-with-arguments in order to create an instance of the class. That means it has to parse the JSON for the constructor arguments, but it doesn't know that the `toDoDate` _constructor parameter_ is related to the `toDoDate` _field_, so it can't use the `@JsonFormat` annotation present on the latter to create an argument for the former. There's also the problem that parameter names are lost during compilation (unless you compile with `-parameters`, at least with `javac` implementation).

Comment: @ssc1234 That said, I believe you could also annotate the constructor parameters if you did not want to add a no-argument constructor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).